# How can I find servers for Primal Carnage?

Tags: primal-carnage

I just bought *Primal Carnage* on the current Steam sale; the original version, not its sequel, *Primal Carnage: Extinction*.

It's a multi-player game. There's no single player mode; you need to join a server. But I can't find any.

[image: Empty Primal Carnage server browser]

The list is empty. Refreshing doesn't help, nor changing the settings.

I've searched with Google for `where can I find primal carnage servers -extinction` and variations thereof, and dug up [some old threads](https://steamcommunity.com/app/215470/discussions/0/828939163643316200/) on the Steam forums, including [one with a proposed solution](https://steamcommunity.com/app/215470/discussions/0/828939978312699595/): verify the game cache, which I did, but to no avail.

**What else can I do to find the servers?**

Version is 1.3.0; build ID is 132188.

---

*Addendum 2018-05-03*

*Well, it may be a bug. After installing it on a new machine, a list of servers showed up and I'm able to play. Upon reloading it is empty occasionally, though.*

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer why did you remove the [tag:networking] tag? This may very well turn out to be a networking issue; perhaps ports I need to open somewhere.

Comment: Tags are about the question, not the answers. Your question is about not seeing servers from the ingame browser, not specifically about networking.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

After some quick searching, it seems that [Primal Carnage: Extinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primal_Carnage:_Extinction) is a remake, not exactly a sequel, of the original which includes both multiplayer and new single player mode.

Going to the [Primal Carnage forums](http://primalcarnageforums.com/) shows that the last post in the 1.3 version of the original was 8/27/2016. Whereas the last post in the section for PC:E was 6/16/2017. This could mean there are simply no servers to join as nobody is online.

I would request a refund from steam assuming you have under 2 hours played. Or find out if there are other small active communities still playing the game.

Answer (score -1):

I have 250 hours of Primal Carnage. I only play the night between 21h and 1h30 ( France), and there are like 10/20 players. And rarely but sometimes you have like 30/40 players at the beginning of the night.

The server browser is bugged, when you leave it for settings and comes back for searching a server, it bugs and it can't find any ( even with refreshing). So you have to leave the game and restart it, and go directly in server browser and never go back.

But sometimes too, at 1h30 of the night, all the servers are shutdown, even if players were playing in. And in this case, you have to wait +/- 30min when the server are up. It's maybe a maintenance idk.